# Overriding UIBarButtons' functions in the tableView

Tags: ios

is there a way to override UIBarButtons' functions in the tableView?

```
- (IBAction)addNewBook:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addNewBook" sender:self];

}

- (IBAction)myBooks:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myBooks" sender:self];
}
```

I made new actions for these two `UIBarButtons` (in Table View) and also tried adding segues to go to new viewControllers when these buttons are pressed, but these `UIBarButtons` already have pre-determined functions - right one's function is to add and the left is to delete. Is there a way to override these functions - so I could get the segues that I want to happen instead of deleting and adding things in the list?

Comment: You want to perform both functions? predetermined and new one? I mean in two different situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag your barItem to NavigationBar in storyBoard and drag segue.
Then delete these codes, Edit and Add not default button,they are set in viewDidLoad.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```